# I want to disable the sublime autocomplete suggestion pop-ups when I type semicolon

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I am using the SublimeCodeIntel package and currently, when I type a semicolon to end a line, Sublime keeps popping up the autocomplete suggestion box:

[image: example of the autocomplete suggestion after putting a semicolon]

Currently, I have to press "Shift+Enter" after semicolon or "Esc" then "Enter" to jump to the next line, but this is very annoying. I don't want to disable autocomplete altogether, instead, I want to disable the autocomplete suggestion pop-ups specifically when I type semicolon ";".

Comment: seems like a popular problem, with no suggestions on how to fix it yet:
https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/627
https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/598
https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/536
https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/470

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you resolved this but I got this behaviour to stop by following instructions posted [here](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel/issues/461):

**On Windows:**

Select Package Settings > SublimeCodeIntel > Key Bindings - User,
and add the following to the `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap - User`:

```
{ 
  "keys": [";"], 
  "command": "run_macro_file", 
  "args": {"file": "Packages/User/unAutoSemiColon.sublime-macro"} 
}
```

And then Select Preferences -> Browse Packages -> Users,
save a file named `unAutoSemiColon.sublime-macro` with the following contents:

```
[
    {
        "args":
        {
            "characters": ";"
        },
        "command": "insert"
    }
]
```

Finally, restart your sublime and the problem will be solved.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work on Macs, but the previous example from your link worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes, this is a Windows solution. I'll update my answer.

Comment: remove the "and"

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. In my case it was due to a package 'Auto Complete JavaScript with Method Signature'. Check your list. If you have this package in the installed package list disable it. The auto completion extensions will not be there.